# $_Post data returns blank Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, database, function

I have a form. I would like to get the input information and send it to the database via 'update_user_meta', however $_POST['this-user'] is giving a blank entry in the database.

The '$user_id' and '$meta_key' are posting to the database but the '$meta_value' is blank.

When I console log $_POST through ajax I get a blank entry in console. When I run .val() in jQuery I also get a blank entry not undefined or NULL.

I have tried having the data section of the code be

```
data: {
            'action': 'hide_this',
            'this-user': this-user,
            'hidebtn2': hidebtn2
        },
```

However a dash can't be in function i.e 'function doAjaxRequest4(hidebtn2,this-user)' is not allowed.

Insight is appreciated.

PHP

```
add_action('wp_ajax_hide_this', 'hide_this_by_id');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_hide_this', 'hide_this_by_id');
function hide_this_by_id()
{
    global $wpdb;

    $labelID4 = 0;
    $postdVlaue2 = $_POST['hidebtn2'];
    $this_user = $_POST['this-user'];
    $alredyclick3 = 0;
    $not_loggedin = 0;
    $userlvlMeta2 = 0;

    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $member_id = SwpmMemberUtils::get_logged_in_members_id();

        $query = "SELECT * FROM " . $wpdb->prefix . "swpm_members_tbl WHERE member_id = %d";
        $userData = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($query, $member_id));

        $membership_levels = $userData->membership_level;

        $labelID4 = $membership_levels;

    } else {
        $not_loggedin = 1;
    }

    if ($labelID4 == 10 ) {
        $userlvlMeta2 = 1;
        $alredyclick3 = get_user_meta($member_id, 'hidden-info', true);
        if (empty($alredyclick3) &&  $postdVlaue2 == 1) {
            update_user_meta($member_id, 'hidden-info', $postdVlaue2);
            update_user_meta($member_id, 'this-user', $this_user);
            $alredyclick3 = 1;
        }
    }

    if ($alredyclick3 == 1) {
        $this_hide2 = 1;
    } else {
        $this_hide2 = 0;
    }

    if ($userlvlMeta2 == 1) {
        $this_Meta2 = 1;
    } else {
        $this_Meta2 = 0;
    }

    $return4 = array(
        'hIdethis2'  => $this_hide2,
        'userlvlMeta2' => $this_Meta2,
        'userlvlNolog' => $not_loggedin,
        'levelid4'  => $labelID4,
        'test'      =>$this_user
    );

    echo json_encode($return4);

    die();
}
```

jQuery

```
function doAjaxRequest4(hidebtn2,getthisInfo) {

    var getthisInfo = jQuery('.this-user > input').val();
    console.log(getthisInfo);

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: ajax_sib_front_object.ajax_url,
        data: {
            'action': 'hide_this',
            'this-user': getthisInfo,
            'hidebtn2': hidebtn2
        },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        type: "post",
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data.test);
            var input = jQuery('.this-user > input');
            var input2 = jQuery('.this-number > input');
            var is_name = input.length > 3;
            var is_name2 = input2.length > 3;

            if (!data.thisdisc2 == 1 && data.userlvlMeta2 == 1) {
                jQuery("#this_col_1").addClass("enable_this");
            } else if (data.thisdisc2 == 1 && is_name && is_name2 ) {
                jQuery("#this_col_1").removeClass("enable_this");
                jQuery("#this_col_2").addClass("enable_this");

            } 
        }
    });
}
```

Function Called by

```
if ($('body').is('.page-id-9999') || $('body').is('.page-id-1111')) {

    var thisbtn = document.querySelector('#this_verf_form > div > .wpcf7');

    thisbtn.addEventListener('wpcf7submit', function (event) {
        var status = event.detail.status;
        console.log(status);
        if (status === 'mail_sent') {
            jQuery('#this_submtID').val("Submitted");
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            doAjaxRequest4(1);
        }, 3500);
    }, false);
}
```

HTML

```
<div role="form" class="wpcf7" id="wpcf7-f9999-p9999-o1" lang="en-US" dir="ltr">
    <div class="screen-reader-response"><p role="status" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true"></p> <ul></ul></div>
    <form action="/mysite/#wpcf7-f9999-p9999-o1" method="post" class="wpcf7-form init" novalidate="novalidate" data-status="init">
    <div class="vc_row" id="this_row">
    <div class="vc_col-sm-5">
    <span class="wpcf7-form-control-wrap this-user"><input type="text" name="this-user" value="" size="40" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text wpcf7-validates-as-required" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" placeholder="placeholder"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="wpcf7-form-control has-spinner wpcf7-submit" id="sub_id">
    </div>
```

Comment: `this-user` isn't a valid variable name. It's an arithmetic expression: `this - user`.

Comment: Just change the variable name to something that's valid, like `this_user`.

Comment: @Barmar I changed the variable name to 'thisuser' and added the info to the function and data in ajax. Now there is a NULL showing up in the database after the from has been submitted. and NULL shows in the console as well.

Comment: You need to post the code that calls the function so we can see how it's being set.

Comment: @Barmar ok I've added how the function is being called.

Comment: `doAjaxRequest4()` requires 2 arguments. You're calling it with only 1 argument, so the second argument defaults to `undefined.`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you! That resolved the issue. I appreciate your help.